# Parsing Twitter & Facebook dates in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm writing a little Rails app & part of that is pulling in a few items from a user's Facebook & Twitter stream. I wish to merge them & then order them in date order.

However, Twitter gives me a date of the format:

```
Sat Mar 31 17:06:21 +0000 2012
```

And Facebook gives me the date as:

```
2012-03-31T16:51:36+0000
```

So the question is, in Ruby, how can I standardise those dates into the same format so I can then sort them?

I've tried doing `Date.parse()` but that seems to just return `2012-31-3` which isn't much use as I need the time as well so I can sort them. I have a feeling I might be missing something relatively straight forward.

Thanks,

Jack,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `DateTime.parse` or `DateTime.strptime`.

```
DateTime.parse("Sat Mar 31 17:06:21 +0000 2012")
#=> #<DateTime: 2012-03-31T17:06:21+00:00 ((2456018j,61581s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

DateTime.strptime("Sat Mar 31 17:06:21 +0000 2012", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
#=> #<DateTime: 2012-03-31T17:06:21+00:00 ((2456018j,61581s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```